# Stack overflow vs stack crash

Tags: c

What is the difference between stack over flow and stack crash. When stack crash occurs?
what is the heap over flow and heap crash.
What happens when stack over flow/heap over flow occurs?

Comment: stack overflow gives you the answer.....don't know about stack crash...lol.......stack overflow is not necessarily damaging your stack, it will simply vomit data out meaning that it doesn't have enough space to keep track of your instructions. Stack crash means that there is a geniune problem in your stack and may/may not be recoverable. heap overflow is when your programme has used up all the heap memory that it was assigned to have. Heap crash could damage other running programmes including the one that caused the crash. Both of 'em together means trouble - e.g. coredump (possibly)

Comment: I've never come across the term "stack crash" before. Where have you heard/read about it?

Comment: Wikipedia explains everything you need to know about stack and heap overflows. It does not know anythingabout "stack crash" and me neither.

Comment: **Stack overflow** - occurs when a stack operation consumes memory beyond the end of the stack, thus possibly causing an illegal memory access. **Stack crash** - no such thing. **Heap overflow** - no such thing, because a heap cannot "overflow" by definition (it is not a stack). Nevertheless, it can run out of free blocks (i.e., run out of memory), which might be the "nearest" thing to what you mean by "heap overflow". **Heap crash** - a heap is typically implemented as a linked list. If that data structure gets corrupted, then any heap operation might lead to a memory access violation.

Comment: Maybe he means **stack corruption**.

Comment: In the cases that I mentioned above for **Stack overflow** and **Heap corruption**, the outcome is generally considered as *undefined behavior*. In practice, you're most likely to get a memory access violation at some point during the execution of your program, but it will not necessarily take place **immediately** after the stack overflow / heap corruption.

Comment: There is no *Heap overflow* but the equivalent is *Heap exhaustion*,

Answer (score 2):

A stack overflow is [extensively discussed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) and means an overflow condition when there's not enough stack memory and other data gets overwritten causing undefined behavior.

"*Stack crash*" is likely a synonymous of the first although I've heard it (or *stack corruption*) to indicate, mostly in a debugging environment, when the stack pointer gets corrupted causing all the debugging stack-related views to stall (and obviously also the debuggee as well).

A heap overflow doesn't usually happen except in some memory-pool-managed circumstances since, assuming the operating system is doing a good job, you will never get to overwrite a used memory chunk by having that marked as writable. If heap memory gets exhausted your system will likely tell you that and fail.

A heap crash might be defined as an invalid use of heap memory, e.g. access violation or accessing invalid addresses. It should fall in the broader terminology of [memory corruption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) and [storage violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_violation) (these might be linked to stack overflows).

Not sure where you've heard of these terms, especially "stack crash", but I wouldn't use it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about **Stack crash**.

In general there is two kind of errors with memory access :

1. you violate some memory protection (trying to write in a readonly
   part or access a memory you mustn't)
2. you access a memory you have right on but in a bad way

**Stack overflow** is generally used when the program intentionally or not corrupts the stack content by overflowing a structure inside it. This is much like case (2).

It is also used when you **overrun the stack**, by interleaving to much function calls for example. This is much like case (1). Java for example gives you a `StackOverflow` exception in this case.

You also have both cases with heap. A *buffer overflow* is an example of accessing memory the bad way and corrupting data in the heap (if the buffer is in the heap). In this case we can say that it is a **Heap overflow**.

You can also try to access some memory in the Heap region of your process that is not currently allocated. This leads you to different scenarios depending of the virtual memory layer. Sometimes you are able to use the memory but as it has not been previously allocated it will leads you to a future memory corruption (not reported at the time it appears and difficult to trace back).
Sometimes the virtual memory layer will be able to detect your access violation and will abort your process (Unix can report it as `Bus error` or `Segmentation fault`).

You can also consume all the Heap space by allocating too much memory. This is a **Heap exhaustion** a kind of *Heap overrun*...